# Create asp.net website with editable config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, installation

I want to create setup of my web application with editable web.config file content.

Any help?

Comment: More info is really needed here please be more specific as well.

Comment: Definitely more content required on what you've done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to change the config with your code, the following should help. Any time you execute the following code, your site will be restarted. So keep that in mind.

```
var config = (Configuration)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var configSection = (MySectionTypeHere)myConfiguration.GetSection("system.web/section");

//make your edits here

myConfiguration.Save();
```

If this is not what you're looking for, perhaps you could provide some more information.

Comment: thanks for reply buddy. but i go with this link http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/578/package-an-application-for-the-windows-web-application-gallery/

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like MS Web deploy. Read more about it here. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/578/package-an-application-for-the-windows-web-application-gallery/